# Showdown with same straight - do pairs count as a tie break?

Tags: all-in, hand-reading

We were playing poker and the board was `T876A`. I had `A9` so I had the straight but I also had a pair of aces. My opponent had `T9` so he completed the straight but also had a pair of `T`s on the side.

I say I should've won but he ended up taking the pot because he said his `T` completed the straight before the `T` came on board.

Who should've won?

Comment: It is a split pot. I am voting to close your question because it already has an answer in the best five cards rule. Please read it, it involves the basics of reading poker hands.

Answer (score 0):

It's a split pot as has been stated in the comments, because you both had the same best 5 card hand - a T high straight. There is no such thing as a "straight and a pair", you both have a straight, that is your best 5 card hand.

Poker is (usually) a game of 5 card hands - other cards you may have access to (in holdem when you have 2 hole cards and up to 5 community cards for example) are irrelevant to determining the winner of a hand if they do not form one of the 5 cards which make up your best possible hand.